# Assigning value to array gives an error

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm aware there are many answers here related to that, I went through a lot of them and I still don't realize what am I doing wrong.

I'm trying to pass an array to another `UIViewController` when a `UITableViewCell` is being tapped. All I have to do is replace the `messageLog.transferedUsers[0]` with the `user`. Doesn't work though.

```
class MessageVC: UIViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        print(user) // prints the user object
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboards.messages, bundle: Bundle.main)
        let messageLog = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageLogVC") as! MessageLogVC
        messageLog.transferedUsers[0] = user // this is the error
        navigationController?.pushViewController(messageLog, animated: true)
    }
 }


 class MessageLogVC : UIViewController { 
       var transferedUsers = [UserModel]()
 }
```

Error states:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is empty. There is no `slot 0` to insert user into, because there's no slots at all.

You need to use `messageLog.transferedUsers.append(user)`, which will create a new space for your `user`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I knew it was very simply but I just blocked. Thank you. I'll accept this answer when the waiting time is over.